# What is the name of this Visual Studio 2010 plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins

I'm watching the PluralSight tutorial videos, and during one of the code samples I noticed this in the solution explorer.

[image: Solution Explorer]

What is the name of the plugin/tool that lists the `All Open Unsaved Edited` in the solution explorer?

Comment: Looks like some plugin to Expand Collapse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a Solution Navigator - part of [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Home) by Microsoft.

Comment: ...which is full of all kinds of other awesome things too.  Including a Add References dialog that doesn't suck and a ctrl-click shortcut for "Go To Definition"

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm surprised I haven't heard about this tool before.

Comment: @Brandon yea its pretty famous.  Do come back here and post your experience about it. Have been thinking about using it a couple of times but I can be a finicky guy!

Answer (score 2):

Its a Solution Navigator. You can read about it from this link

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/20/solution-navigator-blog-post.aspx?PageIndex=4